# system.stdout.flush() not working in phantomjs

Tags: .net, phantomjs, ipc, flush

I'm trying to create a phantomjs script which reads "commands" from standard input and writes the result to standard output INTERACTIVELY. This script is then executed on phantom via a .NET process which will write to and read from the streams. I'm having trouble getting the phantom output on the .NET side: it seems that flush() doesn't do the trick. Here's the minimal phantom code with which I can reproduce the issue:

```
// phantom js "echo server"
var system = require('system'), line;

var line = system.stdin.readLine();
system.stdout.writeLine(line);
system.stdout.flush();
```

The reason I suspect flush is that if I either (1) write enough extra content (presumably overflowing the buffer) after the initial flush() call or (2) follow flush() with a call to phantom.exit(), the .NET process can see the data in standard out.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a known bug? I'm using phantomjs 2.0.0.0.